# Combine two strings/arrays

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if want I want is possible.

```
string1= Blue | Green  | Violet  | Pink

string2= light  | dark  | smooth  | light
```

I need =

```
Blue light | Green dark  | Violet smooth  | Pink light
```

Comment: That's entirely possible, but you need to break it down into smaller steps. Read up more on _arrays_, how to go back and forth from strings, they'll definitely be useful in achieving this.

Comment: Use `split()` to split the strings into arrays. Then loop through the two arrays, concatenating the corresponding members and putting them into a new array. Finally, use `join()` to combine that array into a string.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is split the strings, then iterate through and combine them. It ends up looking like something like this:

```js
// Create strings
var string1 = "Blue | Green  | Violet  | Pink";
var string2 = "light  | dark  | smooth  | light";
var string3 = "";

// Create arrays
var arr1 = string1.split(' | ');
var arr2 = string2.split(' | ');
var arr3 = [];

// Iterate through
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
  arr3.push(arr1[i] + ' ' + arr2[i]);
}

// Join array
var string3 = arr3.join(' | ');
console.log(string3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try!

Comment: It works - great! I'm happy!

Answer (score 0):

There you go. An easy solution using latest JS features like **.reduce**

```js
const firstElements = 'Blue | Green  | Violet  | Pink'.split('|');

const secondElements = 'light  | dark  | smooth  | light'.split('|');

let result = firstElements.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
  let divider = '|';
  if (!secondElements[index + 1]) {
    divider = ''
  }
  return accumulator += ` ${currentValue.trim()} ${secondElements[index].trim()} ${divider}`;

}, "").trim();

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are meaning about all:

- `string1` is one of `Blue`, `Green`, `Violet`, or `Pink`
- `string2` is one of `light`, `dark`, `smooth`, or `light`
- expecting concat them

then, you can `string1 + string2`.

Or, do you mean for arrays?:

```js
const strings1 = ["Blue", "Green", "Violet", "Pink"];
const strings2 = ["light", "dark", "smooth", "light"];
// ["Blue light", "Green dark", "Violet smooth", "Pink light"]
const result = strings1.map((string, index) => [string, strings2[index]])
```